# CSV to a String Array - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file which has only one column with 100+ rows. I would like to put those values in an one dimensional array(only if its possible). So that it works as same as if I wrote a string array manually. I.e.

```
String[] username = {'lalala', 'tatata', 'mamama'}; //<---if I did it manually

String[] username = {after passing the CSV values}; //<---I want this like the above ones.
```

Then later I would like to be able to initialized that class to a different class, say if the class that holds the array is called ArrayClass, I would like to be able to initialized this to different class, like this --

```
public class MainClass{
     ArrayClass array = new ArrayClass();
     //Then I would like to be able to do this
     someMethod(array.username);
}
```

I know I asked a lot of things but I seriously appreciate all your help. Even if you see this question and say THIS IS BS. Oh and one more thing I would prefer it to be in JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to use an arraylist rather than an array as you dont have to worry about number of rows. An array has a fixed size that cant be changed. i.e ArrayList

As you have only one column you will not need to worry about commas in csv

Example code would look something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

  public class MyClass {

  private ArrayList<String> MyArray = new ArrayList<String>();
  private Scanner scan;

  public MyClass(){

    try {
      scan = new Scanner(new File("MyFile.csv"));
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
      System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }

  }

  public ArrayList<String> getArray() {

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
      Scanner line = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
      MyArray.add(line.next());

    }
    return MyArray;
  }

  }
```

And in the main:

```
MyClass f = new MyClass();
System.out.println(f.getArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a csv you can use the split method of string with a proper regex.
Please do check the split method

Answer (score 0):

The first half of your question is easy and can be handled in a number of different ways. Personally, I would use the Scanner class and set the delimiter to be ",". Create a new Scanner Object and then call `setDelimiter(",")` on it. Then simply scan through the tokens. See the example on the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). This method of doing things is effective because it handles reading in the file *and* separating it based on your criteria (the ',' character).